# Fingerprint device disconnected

Tags: fingerprint-reader

When I tried to enroll fingerprint it says Fingerprint device disconnected. But it is working on Windows. I have tried to find a solution over internet but I couldn't find one. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on Asus Vivobook pro

```
sudo lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 13d3:5458 IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f3:0c6e Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 14cd:6116 Super Top M6116 SATA Bridge
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Most fingerprint sensors are “Windows only”. If you can [edit] your question to include the version of Ubuntu you’re using as well as the terminal output of `sudo lsusb`, then it may be possible to offer more specific information about the fingerprint reader in your machine 

Comment: @matigo thanks for the suggestions, lsusb shows the Fingerprint device.

Comment: That particular device [does not appear to work on any current Linux release](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:04f3-0c6e). You will need to wait until someone can reverse-engineer a driver 

Comment: @matigo I have exactly the same problem with the exact same device (`Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f3:0c6e Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint`) with Ubuntu 23.04 on Asus Vivobook Pro 14. How can I help this to process as a user?